# Using intent.Action_call for user inputted number

Tags: android, android-intent

Help me modify with necessary changes needed to use the value/string(number) passed by user for phone-calling that string itself

```
            Intent phnIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            phnIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91987654321"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/call-a-number-directly-from-an-android-application/) link.

Make sure you add the necessary permission in the Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Just add the line `startActivity(phnIntent);`

EDIT:

Activity A

```
Intent someIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
someIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", number);
startAcitivty(someIntent);
```

Acitivity B

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String number = extras.getInt("phoneNumber");
```

Use the `number` string to make the call.

Comment: Its not that i can't do a call to +91987654321,but i want to call the other number present and obtained from my previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this :

String strTelNo = "+91987654321";

Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");

Uri data = Uri.parse("tel:"+ strTelNo );

intent.setData(data);

startActivity(intent);